# How to convert Java List<Date> to Spark Dataset<Row>

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a list of dates that I want to convert  to a spark dataset so that I can use the same in transformations.

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(date1);
```

I expect something like this:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.createDataset(dates);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a *list of Date* then you can create a *List of Row* as

```
List<Row> data = new ArrayList<>();
for(Date date : dates) {
    data.add(RowFactory.create(date));
}
```

and then a `schema` as

```
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[] { 
                new StructField("date", DataTypes.DateType, false, Metadata.empty())
        });
```

and finally use the *List of Row* and `schema` to create the *dataset* as

```
    Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema);
```

which should give you a valid *dataset*

I hope the answer is helpful